# How phenyl shift is possible in Benzil-benzilic rearrangement?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds

We know $\ce{C-C}$ bond is much stronger than $\ce{C-OH}$ bond (because similar sized atoms have maximum overlap) as in case of phenyl-carbonyl carbon bond. Also due to resonance there is double bond character in phenyl-carbon linkage. Then how does that bond break to give phenyl shift?

Comment: The rearrangement is driven by the (effectively irreversible) deprotonation of the carboxylic acid, not by bond strengths

Comment: I have a feeling you didn't read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzilic_acid_rearrangement which describes mechanism well.

Comment: I have a feeling you didn't read my question well as I asked why phenyl shifts instead of oxygen linkages as oxygen have lone pairs to form three member cyclic transition state easily than phenyl whose bond strength is much high even to form that trasition ring easily than -OH  @ Mithoron

Comment: A hydroxide anion attacks one of the ketone groups in 1 in a nucleophilic addition to form the alkoxide 2. The next step requires a bond rotation to conformer 3 which places the migrating group R in position for attack on the second carbonyl group. In a concerted step, the migrating R group attacks the α-carbonyl group forming another alkoxide with concomitant formation of a keto-group at the other carbon. This migration step is rate-determining. (1/2)

Comment: This sequence resembles a nucleophilic acyl substitution. Calculations show that when R is methyl the charge build-up on this group in the transition state can be as high as 0.22, and that the methyl group is positioned between the central carbon–carbon bond. (2/2)

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Benzilic_Acid_Rearrangement_Mechanism.png/750px-Benzilic_Acid_Rearrangement_Mechanism.png - the above description is with reference to the above image and the description itself is Wikipedia sourced.